# Android text to speech in different languages

Tags: java, android, locale

I want to make an application that can support different languages.

There is no problem with the "default" languages:

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

And also some other:

```
Locale l = new Locale("ru","RU");
tts.setLanguage(l);
```

But a lot of others don't work, eg.:

```
Locale l = new Locale("hu","HU");
tts.setLanguage(l);
```

I have also tried `"hu"`, `"hu-HU"`, `"hu-rHU"`, `"HU"`... but nothing...

Also, it doesn't work with Turkish, Greek, Dutch, Czech...

Comment: Addition: SM-T867 can't run Locale.ITALY and Locale.ITALIAN, but SM-N950F can run Locale.ITALY and Locale.ITALIAN. Plus, with new Android version the sound library changes, and even English speaker's sound is different, and other languages' sound is different. I really want Android Team to work on this translation services.

Answer (score 6):

Not all are supported, use: [Locale.getAvailableLocales()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales()) to get available possible locales and test them against [isLanguageAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable(java.util.Locale)), or since api21 you can use [getAvailableLanguages()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getAvailableLanguages()) to directly get available languages for current TTS engine. You can install alternative TTS engine, ie. SVOX is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

When you type **Locale.** the dropdown list opens, and available languages are listed as below:

1. Korean
2. Italian
3. German
4. Japanese
5. French
6. English
7. Canada_French
8. Chinese
9. Simplified_Chinese
10. Taiwan
11. Traditional Chinese
12. UK
13. US

There is no Hungarian (Magyarul), Turkish (Türkçe) available at this time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to **change your phone's system language** to Greek, Turkish, Dutch or whatever language you want, in order the Locale, take your Default Locale Language.
I wrote *println* in order to check if the program takes your system language right

```
println(Locale.getDefault().country)
tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault())
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ISO 639 alpha-2` or `alpha-3` code for first parameter. It is `"rus"` for Russian language. And `ISO 3166 alpha-2` for second parameter. It is correct (`"RU"`).

Here is list of ISO country codes:

[ISO 639](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes)

[ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes)