# TTS android studio doesn't work in android device

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech, samsung-mobile

I am creating a language learning app and it needs a TTS. There is no problem with my codes and the locale I've set it is FRANCE/FRENCH which is available/supported with android studio but when I tried to run/install my app in my Samsung android device. The set locale wasn't working, its still in english.

here is my code:

```
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

            textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.FRANCE);

        }
    });

    listView = findViewById(R.id.items_listviewFRE);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomItemAdapter());

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            textToSpeech.speak(array[position], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        }
    });

}
```

'''

Comment: Note that [only `Locale.US` – this locale is guaranteed to be available on all devices](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale)

Comment: Also see: [Android text to speech in different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33944651/295004)